# null reference Exception in a PtrToStructure C#

Tags: c#, pointers, structure, nullreferenceexception, logitech

the visual studio 2019 send this excepción

i got this

```
public struct DIJOYSTATE2ENGINES
{
    public int lX;              /* x-axis position              */
    public int lY;              /* y-axis position              */
    public int lZ;              /* z-axis position              */
    public int lRx;             /* x-axis rotation              */
    public int lRy;             /* y-axis rotation              */
    public int lRz;             /* z-axis rotation              */
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public int[] rglSlider;     /* extra axes positions         */
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public uint[] rgdwPOV;      /* POV directions               */
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 128)]
    public byte[] rgbButtons;   /* 128 buttons                  */
    public int lVX;             /* x-axis velocity              */
    public int lVY;             /* y-axis velocity              */
    public int lVZ;             /* z-axis velocity              */
    public int lVRx;            /* x-axis angular velocity      */
    public int lVRy;            /* y-axis angular velocity      */
    public int lVRz;            /* z-axis angular velocity      */
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public int[] rglVSlider;    /* extra axes velocities        */
    public int lAX;             /* x-axis acceleration          */
    public int lAY;             /* y-axis acceleration          */
    public int lAZ;             /* z-axis acceleration          */
    public int lARx;            /* x-axis angular acceleration  */
    public int lARy;            /* y-axis angular acceleration  */
    public int lARz;            /* z-axis angular acceleration  */
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public int[] rglASlider;    /* extra axes accelerations     */
    public int lFX;             /* x-axis force                 */
    public int lFY;             /* y-axis force                 */
    public int lFZ;             /* z-axis force                 */
    public int lFRx;            /* x-axis torque                */
    public int lFRy;            /* y-axis torque                */
    public int lFRz;            /* z-axis torque                */
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public int[] rglFSlider;    /* extra axes forces            */
};                                             
                                              
  [DllImport("LogitechSteeringWheelEnginesWrapper", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr LogiGetStateENGINES(int index);
```

this is the context  as you see i got the DIJOYSTATE2ENGINES and the method LogiGetStateENGINES() that return a intptr

but when i use the ptrtoStrurcture in this sentente make the null reference
.

```
ret = (DIJOYSTATE2ENGINES)Marshal.PtrToStructure(LogiGetStateENGINES(index), typeof (DIJOYSTATE2ENGINES));
```

of this method.

```
public static DIJOYSTATE2ENGINES LogiGetStateCSharp(int index)
{
    DIJOYSTATE2ENGINES ret = new DIJOYSTATE2ENGINES();
    ret.rglSlider = new int[2];
    ret.rgdwPOV = new uint[4];
    ret.rgbButtons = new byte[128];
    ret.rglVSlider = new int[2];
    ret.rglASlider = new int[2];
    ret.rglFSlider = new int[2];
    try
    {
        ret = (DIJOYSTATE2ENGINES)Marshal.PtrToStructure(LogiGetStateENGINES(index), typeof (DIJOYSTATE2ENGINES));
    }
    catch (System.ArgumentException)
    {
        Debug.Write("Exception catched");
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: i hope you can help me? Good day

Comment: Put the return value from `LogiGetStateENGINES(index)` in a variable and examine it, it's probably `0`

Comment: i did it,but i got the same results @Charlieface

Comment: So what was the result of that function

Comment: this System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' with this modification                                                                                                   IntPtr prueba = new IntPtr();
        prueba = LogiGetStateENGINES(index);
        try
        {
            ret = (DIJOYSTATE2ENGINES)Marshal.PtrToStructure(prueba, typeof (DIJOYSTATE2ENGINES));
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentException)
        {
            Debug.Write("Exception catched");
        }
        return ret;
    }@Charlieface

Comment: Did you debug it? Breakpoint it at `try{` and check the value of  `prueba`

Comment: `0x0000000000000000` this is the value of `prueba` @Charlieface

Comment: Then I suggest you investigate why `LogiGetStateENGINES` returns that. In the meantime I think this question should be closed due to lack of info.